# How to record fine-grained CPU data for JavaScript methods executed via Nashorn

Tags: perfino

Is it possible to configure the fine-grained CPU profile to record method invocations for the NashornScriptEngine?

I'm trying to analyse some very slow requests in a web server. I have configured a trigger in Perfino that records "fine-grained CPU data in profiling mode", so I can use JProfiler to inspect this data. But I cannot find how to make Perfino recurse into NashornScriptEngine methods:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the method sampling configuration you can delete the "jdk." filter to measure these packages.

[image]